# Storing multiple entry into linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a text file consists of multiple journal entries which I can read it and store it into a struct called Journal. But my problem now is that I dont know how to add it into the linked list 1 by 1.

this is my insert method

```
void insertStart (LinkedList *list, Journal *JEntry) {
    Node *newNode;
    newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data.day = JEntry->day;
    newNode->data.month = JEntry->month;
    newNode->data.year = JEntry->year;
    strcpy(newNode->data.entry, JEntry->entry);


    if (list == NULL) {
        list->head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode->next = list->head;
        list->head = newNode;
    }
    printf("Inserted Entry = %d/%d/%d :%s\n", newNode->data.day, newNode->data.month, newNode->data.year, newNode->data.entry);
}
```

and this is

```
fscanf(fo, "%d", &numEntry);
journal = (Journal *)malloc(numEntry * sizeof(Journal));

for (i=0; i<numEntry;i++) {
    fscanf(fo, "%d/%d/%d\n", &journal[i].day, &journal[i].month, &journal[i].year);
    fgets(journal[i].entry, SIZE, fo);

    }

    insertStart(list, journal);
    index = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d-%02d-%02d: %s\n", journal[index].year, journal[index].month, journal[index].day, journal[index].entry);
    free(journal);
    fclose(fo);
}
```

this is my struct

```
#define SIZE 102
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char entry[SIZE];
} Journal;


typedef struct Node {
    Journal data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node *head;
} LinkedList;
```

if I put the insertStart in the for loop, yes it entered 4 times, but its the same result over and over again.

if i put it to where it is shown above, it will only run 1 time.

my question now is how can i store the rest of the entry into the linked list? thank you

this is the content of the text file

```
4
12/04/2010 
Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes. 
18/04/2010 
Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget. 
03/05/2010 
Was asked today if I was an art exhibit. 
19/05/2010 
Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

the first number `4` is the number of entries in case anyone's wondering.

Comment: This will go wrong: `if (list == NULL) { list->head = newNode; }` because you are dereferencing that `NULL` pointer.

Comment: You need to create a `LinkedList` struct and set the `head` pointer to NULL. In the insert method, you should check whether `list->head` is NULL. `list` should never be NULL in that method.

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()` etc. It is unnecessary and can mask the serious error of a missing prototype.

Comment: @mlp can you explain further about it? can i only cast it when i deal with void* ? or in what scenario will i ever want to cast ? thank you

Comment: `void*` is automatically converted to whatever object-pointer type it's assigned to. Absorb http://c-faq.com/, and later http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered just storing JEntry in the node instead of making a copy?

```
typedef struct 
{
  Journal* data;
  struct Node* next'
} 
Node;
```

That way this can be simplified

```
void insertStart (LinkedList *list, Journal *JEntry) 
{
  Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newNode->data = JEntry;
  newNode->next = NULL;
```

instead of having a

```
struct { Node* head } LinkedList
```

just declare it

```
Node* list;
```

if you want to change the pointer pass it in as a double pointer

```
void insertStart( Node** list, Journal* JEntry)  /* insertStart(&list,journal + i) */
```

If list already has an entry, make sure your new node points to that

```
if (*list != NULL) 
{
  newNode->next = *list;
}
```

Now make your list point to the new node

```
*list = newNode;
```

When printing use -> for JEntry as well.

```
printf("Inserted Entry = %d/%d/%d :%s\n", newNode->data->day, newNode->data->month, newNode->data->year, newNode->data->entry);
```

Comment: Oh whoa, I didn't know i could do this (journal + i), how does it work? I dont really understand that part. thank you for the answer

Comment: @JamesWong since journal is the starting address of your array you can add an integer as offset to it, it is basically the same as writing `&journal[i] `

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set `list->head` to `NULL` when you create it (or use `calloc` instead of `malloc`).

However, your problem comes from the line `insertStart(list,journal);`.  Although `journal` is the pointer to the beginning of an array of `Journal` objects, `insertStart` doesn't know that.  It dereferences the pointer and only adds the first journal entry to the list.

Comment: why use calloc instead of malloc?

Comment: `calloc` sets all of the newly allocated memory to zero.  That way, your `next` field is automatically set to `NULL`.